# How to setup W3C Unicorn validator for local URIs?

Tags: macos, tomcat6, macports, w3c-validation, unicorn

I frequently need to check not-yet-public websites so cannot use a public online validator. I tried to install W3C’s [Unicorn](http://code.w3.org/unicorn) on my OSX (10.7) machine using MacPorts (because I didn’t want to cope with dependencies). Unfortunately the docs for Unicorn installation are mostly missing or outdated, and the mailing list looks dead.
Disclaimer: I don’t know Java.

Here’s what I did:

- install Java update to 1.6.0_29 (since Apple’s current one has a memory leak)
- install Tomcat and dependencies (ivy is missing in docs and doesn’t get downloaded automatically as it is supposed to):

  ```
  sudo port install apache-ant apache-ivy tomcat6 mercurial
  ```
- select Python version for Mercurial; perhaps better use python.org-Python and install Mercurial there, but I’ve only system and MacPort’s Python on this machine:

  ```
  sudo port select python python27
  ```
- automatically start Tomcat after reboot:

  ```
  sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.tomcat6.plist
  ```
- add setup to `.profile`:

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK
  export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6
  ```
- check output of `java -version` (my Java version in "A" or "Current" was broken; `java -version` just hang)
- fix Java binary path; if there's no `$JAVA_HOME/bin`:

  ```
  cd $JAVA_HOME; sudo ln -s Commands bin
  ```
- restart
- check if tomcat runs on `http://localhost:8080` (ok)
- get and compile unicorn:

  ```
  cd ~/workspace
  hg clone https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/unicorn
  cd unicorn
  ant retrieve compress-css compress-js war cli
  ```
- install unicorn in tomcat:

  ```
  sudo cp dist/unicorn.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
  sudo cp WebContent/resources/tomcat_policy/* $CATALINA_HOME/conf/
  ```
- *yes it works*, but only for public addresses; we need to change

  - one setting in `unicorn.properties`: `ACCEPT_LOCAL_ADDRESSES = true`
  - validator paths in `observers.properties` from `http://validator.w3.org/.../*.wadl` to `file:///.../*.wadl`
- I can change `*.properties` in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/unicorn/WEB-INF/classes` or (better) in `~/workspace/unicorn/WebContent/WEB_INF/conf`. But changes to the latter never make it into the `.war`, don’t know why. (Maybe they’re pacifist?) If `*.properties.default` are renamed to `*.properties`, they’re missing in the distribution, if I don’t rename them, changes are ignored. I found a hint to include that conf-path in `$CLASSPATH`, but that didn’t help either.
- So I copy the adapted configs into the installed webapp, and Unicorn seems to run - but validation results in a white page (status code = 200, but content length = 0).
- In tomcat’s error log I find only (don’t know if that’s important):

  ```
  INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/local/share/java/tomcat6/webapps/unicorn/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. 
  See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
  ```

### CLI

Inbetween I tried if the command line interface is usable. `java -jar unicorn.jar` shows some usage hints, but validation of anything fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at org.w3c.unicorn.UnicornClient.main(UnicornClient.java:113)
```

### Finally

What can I do?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? If not: Did you find another solution?

Comment: No, never got it to work; changed my field of work and lost interest, sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AbstractMethodError on calling Exception.printStackTrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777710/abstractmethoderror-on-calling-exception-printstacktrace)